# Flex layout column width in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to break some elements in different order on mobile, i have something like this now

[image]

And my html

```
  <main>
    <div data-color="yellow"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div data-color="orange"></div>
      <div data-color="purple"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Here is my css

```
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  div {
    flex: 1;
  }

  [data-color=purple] {
    order: 3;
  }

  main.mobile {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  main.mobile .wrapper {
    display: contents;
  }

  main.mobile [data-color=orange] {
    order: -2;
  }
```

I made it simple that you can help me, what i need is that now palge lpaut is half and half, i need **yellow** container to be 75% and right 25%, i am using boostrap 4 but I am not so good at fex layout

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
main {
 display: flex;
}
[data-color="yellow"] {
 flex: 0 0 75%;
}
.wrapper{
 flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

Comment: This way wrapper goes on the left and yellow on the right?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

you can use `flex: 1 percentage();` for example `flex: 1 percentage(1/4);`

Here I made an example in codepen for you:
https://codepen.io/Alirezaaraby/pen/JjYJMZW?editors=1100

Comment: I added an example